# Writing into file using ofstream

Tags: c++, file, printf, ofstream

I have Structure which contains three types and i am trying to write it into my txt file. After all when i open my file i get chars which contatins information and the integer is transformed into binary symbols. i used function

```
sprintf_s(router, "%d" , route[i].route_number);
```

to transform my int into char. And after all this int is transformed and i can see my digit , but beside chars i still get some trash. Here is my code. What i am doing wrong ?

```
ofstream file_not_binary("D:\\nobin.txt",ios::out);
char router[10];
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
 sprintf_s(router, "%d" , route[i].route_number);
 file_not_binary.write((char*) &router,sizeof(router));
 file_not_binary.write((char*) &route[i].destination  ,sizeof(router));
 file_not_binary.write((char*) &route[i].route_number, sizeof(router));
   }
```

I get something like this :
23 юююююююrivne НННН   kiev Н394 ююююююrivne ННННЉ  ээээ««
I typed:  23 rivne kiev  , kiev 394 rivne.

Comment: Ixnay on the pointer casts, seriously.  If you think you need a pointer cast, you're wrong, or the API is broken.

Comment: The last two `sizeof(router)`s should be `sizeof(route[i].destination)` and `sizeof(route[i].route_number)` respectively.

Comment: You get garbage because you are writing junk from `router` which comes after the null terminator. This is a bad idea, but especially bad when the file is open in text mode.

Comment: What does your structure look like, and why are you writing `route_number` twice? Why are you writing binary values to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the following code

```
file_not_binary.write((char*) &router,sizeof(router));
to
file_not_binary.write((char*) &router,strlen(router));
```

The sizeof(router) is the size of array,
but strlen(router) is the length of route[i].route_number. You want to write the route_number(int) to the file, not the array.